# "Unable to handle Aura Definition 'XYZ/XYZ.js': deftype not supported". What does it mean?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, deployment

I am trying to deploy an Aura component, which is a wrapper for a LWC, using Visual Studio, but I am unable to.

Visual Studio tells me:

```
14:31:10.125 Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org
=== Deploy Errors
14:31:11.229 ended SFDX: Deploy Source to Org
```

So not very helpful. The implementation status in Salesforce itself gives a bit more detail:

```
UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Unable to handle Aura Definition 'TradeWindowWrapperV20210726/TradeWindowWrapperControllerV20210726.js': deftype not supported
```

The cmp file looks like this:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasSObjectName,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">    
    <aura:html tag="style">
        .slds-modal__container {
            width: 99%;
            max-width: 99%;
        }
    </aura:html>
    <c:tradeWindowV20210726 recordId="{!v.recordId}" onclose="{!c.modalClose}"/>
</aura:component>
```

and the js file looks like this:

```
({
  modalClose : function(component, event) {
    $A.get('e.force:closeQuickAction').fire();
    const urlToNavigateTo = event.getParam('navigateToURL');
    if (urlToNavigateTo) {
      var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
      urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": urlToNavigateTo
      });
      urlEvent.fire();
    }
  }
})
```

The LWC itself exists, I have checked that in Salesforce.

This Aura component is a clone of another Aura component, which I have deployed successfully. The only difference is the reference to the LWC component.

Comment: P.S. There is no LWC here. It's confusing naming, but LWC is a completely different type of component from Aura.

Comment: The LWC is named tradeWindowV20210726, referenced to in the cmp file. The wrapper is necessary to start the LWC using an action. I have given the LWC and its Aura wrapper similar names.

Comment: I meant only that the actual problem was Aura related, not LWC related. 

Comment: I have removed the LWC tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file name for the Aura Component's Controller is wrong. `TradeWindowWrapperV20210726/TradeWindowWrapperControllerV20210726.js` should be `TradeWindowWrapperV20210726/TradeWindowWrapperV20210726Controller.js`. The controller for an Aura component must named *`ComponentName`*`Controller.js`.

Comment: Once again, @sfdcfox saves the day!